# How do you return the description of a procedure in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

Suppose I have something like this:

```
(define pair (cons 1 (lambda (x) (* x x))
```

If I want to return the front object of the pair I do this:

```
(car pair)
```

And it returns 1. However when the object is a procedure I don't get the exact description of it.
In other words:

```
(cdr pair)
```

returns `#<procedure>` and not `(lambda (x) (*x x))`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to do this or it just a matter of curiosity?

Comment: I would recon that this not possible, since the `lambda` expression has been compiled, and the source code has not been stored along with the compiled code. You may find complicated ways using `racket/decompiler` but I also wonder why you need to do this.

Comment: (pp (cdr pair))-->(lambda (x) (* x x)) at least in mit-scheme. Don't know about racket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to view a function's source code from within the Racket REPL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114295/is-there-a-way-to-view-a-functions-source-code-from-within-the-racket-repl)

Answer (score 8):

Although there's no way to do this generally, you can rig up something to do it for procedures that you define.

1. Racket `struct`s can define a `prop:procedure` that allows the struct to be applied (called) as a procedure. The same struct can hold a copy of your original syntax for the function definition. That's what the `sourced` struct is doing, below.
2. The `write-sourced` stuff is simply to make the output cleaner (show only the original sexpr, not the other struct fields).
3. The `define-proc` macro makes it simpler to initialize the struct -- you don't need to type the code twice and hope it matches. It does this for you.

---

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax racket/syntax))

;; Optional: Just for nicer output
(define (write-sourced x port mode)
  (define f (case mode
              [(#t) write]
              [(#f) display]
              [else pretty-print])) ;nicer than `print` for big sexprs
  (f (sourced-sexpr x) port))

(struct sourced (proc sexpr)
        #:property prop:procedure (struct-field-index proc)
        ;; Optional: Just to make cleaner output
        #:methods gen:custom-write
        [(define write-proc write-sourced)])

;; A macro to make it easier to use the `sourced` struct
(define-syntax (define-proc stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ (id arg ...) expr ...)
     #'(define id (sourced (lambda (arg ...) expr ...)
                           '(lambda (arg ...) expr ...)))]))

;; Example
(define-proc (foo x)
  (add1 x))

(foo 1) ; => 2
foo     ; => '(lambda (x) (add1 x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The procedure `cons` evaluates its arguments: 1 is self-evaluating to 1; `(lambda ...)` evaluates to an anonymous procedure.  If you want to 'prevent' evaluation, you need to `quote` the argument, as such:

```
> (define pair (cons 1 '(lambda (x) (* x x))
> (cdr pair)
(lambda (x) (* x x))
```