# Converting string into lambda/value

Tags: scheme, eval, racket

I want the following code to work:

```
(define fn.str "(lambda (x) (displayln x)")
(define fn.callable (string->lambda fn.str))
; and then 2 next lines should be valid
(fn.callable 123)
(apply fn.callable '(321))
```

But best I can get is to eval string and get output, instead
my target is to get the actual holding value (λ in this case).

In general, this is also desired effect:

```
(define val.num "500")
(define val.li "'(1 2 3)")
(define val.fn "(λ (a) a)")
(define num (string->value val.num)) ; => num is now holding 500
(define li (string->value val.li)) ; => list '(1 2 3)
(define fn (string->value val.fn)) ; => callable lambda
```

Maybe I came close enough to solution, but it's got bad smell.

More info:

- Those strings came into program from outside (file/user input).
- Extracted/parsed values should be binded to something (hash table, for example) for further access.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349543/how-do-you-return-the-description-of-a-procedure-in-scheme. Although, if you really want to take arbitrary user strings and eval them, you might need `eval`. When possible it's preferable to make your own `#lang` in Racket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about something - evaluating code from a string is a bad code smell… maybe there's a better way to do what you want to accomplish. Anyway, here's a possible solution:

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

(define (eval-string str)
  (eval (call-with-input-string str read) ns))
```

It works as requested for the sample inputs:

```
(define fn.str "(lambda (x) (displayln x))")
(define fn.callable (eval-string fn.str))
(fn.callable 123)
=> 123

(apply fn.callable '(321))
=> 321

(define val.num "500")
(eval-string val.num)
=> 500

(define val.li "'(1 2 3)")
(eval-string val.li)
=> '(1 2 3)

(define val.fn "(λ (a) a)")
(eval-string val.fn)
=> #<procedure>
```

Comment: Using this solution this way: `(hash-ref! h key (eval-str "(λ (x y) '(y x))"))` causes arity mismatch. Manual check and `hash-set!` is better choice here (maybe it is obvious, but not for me), at least with this approach.

Comment: @IskanderSharipov that sounds more like a problem with the way you're actually using the function when you get it from the hash table, not with the approach itself.