# "Smart" comparison of functions in Racket

Tags: function, compare, racket

I've got a bit exotic situation. I need to compare functions, but rather by their "origin" than by "instances". Here what I actually mean:

```
(define-values (a b c d) (values #f #f #f #f))

(define (f x)
  (let ([g (λ (y) (printf "Please tell ~a this is ~a\n" x y))]
        [h (curry printf "Don't tell ~a this is ~a\n" x)])
    (if a
        (set! b g)
        (set! a g))
    (if c
        (set! d h)
        (set! c h))))

(f "me")
(f " me")

(a "possible")
(d "impossible")

(equal? a b) ; <====  Is it possible to compare these guys
(equal? c d) ; <====  to get #t in both cases?
```

In both cases we get two different "instances" of functions (even with different values captured), but both declared in the same location of the source code. Of course, getting the actual text of the body of those functions will solve the problem, but other answers here on SO tell that this is impossible in Racket. Are there some tricks that can help me?

**Edit**:
This is not the question on theoretical equivalence of functions. This is completely technical question, much rather on Racket's functions representation in a compiled code. So it can be reformulated, for example, in a following way: can I get the line number of some routine from 'user' code? I suppose this should be feasible because Racket debugger somehow obtains it.

Comment: Are you looking for semantic equality of lambda expressions?

Comment: @JonChesterfield I think more "lightweight" variant. It is not necessary to get `#t` if two identical functions declared in two different places. It is sufficient to get `#t` if function values are declared in the same line and position in code.

Comment: That's probably solvable. Iirc racket tags expressions with debug information so one approach would be to parse that. Beyond that I've got nothing, but at least you don't need a symbolic proof system :)

Comment: @JonChesterfield, yeah, that is completely technical question :) By the way, thanks for the hint with debug information! Maybe I could dig a bit into it.

Comment: “Other answers tell that this is impossible in Racket.” It’s not just impossible in Racket, but it is **provably impossible** in *any* turing complete programming language. Anyway, the thing you are trying to do might be sort of possible with macros, but it seems like a bad idea. This smells strongly of [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @AlexisKing Thanks for the comment. "it is provably impossible in any turing complete programming language". I guess my problem description is too obscure. I've edited the question.

Comment: An object is different even when the same code creates it as long as it happens in different point in time. In this case even the functions are different since they have different free variables and then might result in different result when applied with the same arguments. The compiler has access to information the runtime cannot. eg. the closure is often a two part structure where one would be the very same compiled bytecode and the other will be two different environments.

Comment: @Sylwester Thanks for the response. Your statement is obviously true -- in fact, functions are different even when they capture same values (if environments are the same, `equal?` still returns `#f`). But does that mean that it is impossible to compare "origins" of functions? I mean how does Racket debugger highlight the current point of execution? Maybe somehow reusing this information will tell us that when two closures are executed, they invoke the same piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done even without support from racket internals if you control the code that makes the functions. If you keep a counter (or some identifier) that will denote the particular lambda it can wrap different closures in a struct that can have the same identity from macro expansion. Here is a demonstration:

```scm
#lang racket

;; makes a procedure object that can have other data connected to it
(struct proc (id obj) 
  #:property prop:procedure
  (struct-field-index obj)
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc x port mode)
     (display (format "#<procedure-id-~a>" (proc-id x)) port))])

;; compares the ids of two proc objects if they are proc objects
(define (proc-equal? a b)
  (and (proc? a)
       (proc? b)
       (= (proc-id a) (proc-id b))))

;; extends equal?, candidate to provide
(define (equal*? a b)
  (or (proc-equal? a b)
      (equal? a b)))

;; the state we keep
(begin-for-syntax
  (define unique-proc-id-per-code 0))

;; a macro that changes (lambda* ...) to 
;; (proc expansion-id (lambda ...)) 
(define-syntax (lambda* stx)
  (let ((proc-id unique-proc-id-per-code))
    (set! unique-proc-id-per-code (add1 unique-proc-id-per-code))
    #`(proc #,(datum->syntax stx proc-id) (lambda #,@(datum->syntax stx (cdr (syntax-e stx)))))))


;; test with making a counter
(define counter-from
  (lambda* (from)
    (lambda* ()
      (begin0
        from
        (set! from (add1 from))))))

;; evaluatin the outer shows it has id 0
counter-from ; ==> #<procedure-id-0>

;; make two counters that both use the inner lambda
(define from10 (counter-from 10))
(define from20 (counter-from 20))

;; both have the same expansion id
from10 ; ==> #<procedure-id-1>
from20 ; ==> #<procedure-id-1>

;; they are not equal?
(equal? from10 from20)      ; ==> #f (different object instances of proc)
;; but they are procedure-equal?
(proc-equal? from10 from20) ; ==> #t (same id, thus came from same macroexpansion)
```

Disclaimer: I'm more a schemer than a racketeer so this could perhaps have been done more elegantly and I have no idea what performance penalties this will give.

Comment: This idea is looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/20362858, I've regarded it. Although macro-solution will not work for externally-defined lambdas, it seems that I still should accept this way. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @dvvrd I think the solution actually is based on that answer since I based it on a file in my junk directory called visual-lambda.rkt :-)