# How do I customize the printing of a procedure in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

Suppose I used the following procedures to implement a primitive class:

```
;;; Constructor.
(define (make-pos x y)
  (lambda (msg)
    (cond [(eq? msg 'get-x) x]
          [(eq? msg 'get-y) y]
          [(eq? msg 'set-x) (lambda (v) (set! x v))]
          [(eq? msg 'set-y) (lambda (v) (set! y v))]
          [else (error "POS invalid msg" msg)])))

;;; Getters and setters.
(define (pos-x pos) (pos 'get-x))
(define (pos-y pos) (pos 'get-y))
(define (set-pos-x! pos x) ((pos 'set-x) x))
(define (set-pos-y! pos y) ((pos 'set-y) y))
```

I know that Racket has an object system, but I am making this just for educational purposes. My problem is: how do I customize the printing/displaying of a procedure? For example:

```
(define mypos (make-pos 1 2))
(displayln mypos)
```

This displays something like `#<procedure:...xxx/test.rkt:4:2>`, which is not ideal. Is there a way to customize the output?

EDIT: I would like `(displayln mypos)` to display `(POS (x 1) (y 2))`.

Comment: Well, how do you want it to display? If you want to see the body of lambda, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771620/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-body-of-a-lambda-in-racket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 ways:

1. statically naming the lambda
2. dynamically naming the procedure
3. making a struct with `prop:procedure`

Method (1) is very limited, where you can change `#<procedure:...xxx/test.rkt:4:2>` to `#<procedure:my-constant-name>` by naming the lambda:

```lisp
(define my-constant-name
  (lambda (msg) ....))
my-constant-name
; #<procedure:my-constant-name>
```

Method (2) using `procedure-rename` lets you change the name dynamically, but it doesn't let you get rid of the `#<procedure >` part:

```
(procedure-rename
 (lambda (msg) ....)
 'my-new-name)
; #<procedure:my-new-name>
```

Method (3) using a struct is more powerful. It lets you change the printing to anything you want:

```lisp
(struct proc/print [proc print]
  #:property prop:procedure (struct-field-index proc)
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc self out mode)
     ((proc/print-print self) out))])
(proc/print
 (lambda (msg) ....)
 (lambda (out)
   (display "whatever you want" out)))
; whatever you want
```

If you want to display the s-expression representation of the lambda, you can do that:

```lisp
(struct proc/sexpr [proc sexpr]
  #:property prop:procedure (struct-field-index proc)
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc self out mode)
     (write (proc/sexpr-sexpr self) out))])
(define-simple-macro (lam stuff ...)
  (proc/sexpr (lambda stuff ...) '(lam stuff ...)))
(lam (msg) ....)
; (lam (msg) ....)
```

#### Update: displaying `(POS (x 1) (y 2))`

Using method (3) and a `proc/get-sexpr` struct (like the `proc/sexpr` struct above but with an extra lambda), you can get it to display as `(POS (x 1) (y 2))` like this:

```lisp
(struct proc/get-sexpr [proc get-sexpr]
  #:property prop:procedure (struct-field-index proc)
  #:methods gen:custom-write
  [(define (write-proc self out mode)
     (write ((proc/get-sexpr-get-sexpr self)) out))])

(define (make-pos x y)
  (proc/get-sexpr
    (lambda (msg)
      (cond [(eq? msg 'get-x) x]
            [(eq? msg 'get-y) y]
            [(eq? msg 'set-x) (lambda (v) (set! x v))]
            [(eq? msg 'set-y) (lambda (v) (set! y v))]
            [else (error "POS invalid msg" msg)]))
    (lambda () `(POS (x ,x) (y ,y)))))

;;; Getters and setters.
(define (pos-x pos) (pos 'get-x))
(define (pos-y pos) (pos 'get-y))
(define (set-pos-x! pos x) ((pos 'set-x) x))
(define (set-pos-y! pos y) ((pos 'set-y) y))
```

Using that, calling `(make-pos 1 2)` produces a value that displays as `(POS (x 1) (y 2))`.

```lisp
> (define x (make-pos 1 2))
> x
(POS (x 1) (y 2))
> ((x 'set-x) 10)
> x
(POS (x 10) (y 2))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have edited the question to show how I would like `mypos` to be displayed. I don't understand method (3). Could you provide a concrete example using the information in my edit?

Comment: Okay. I have updated my answer to show how to display it as `(POS (x 1) (y 2))`

Comment: Although I think it won't update after a mutation...

Comment: Okay, I've fixed it so it works with mutation now.